# Apple TV 4K + LG Computer Monitor: Apple remote has but loses volume control

Tags: appletv, remote-control

**Equipment:**

- [Apple TV 4K](https://www.apple.com/apple-tv-4k/) with remote.
- 43" inch computer monitor [LG 43UD79-B 4K](https://www.lg.com/uk/support/product/lg-43UD79-B.AEU) with built-in speakers, has its own remote.

**Connection:**
HDMI, from Apple TV to monitor

**Problem**

When I first connected the Apple TV to this monitor I was able to control the volume on the monitor using the Apple Remote. Handy, one remote for everything!

After a couple of days and for no discernible reason that functionality disappeared. What did work was the monitor's remote for the volume. But that means using two remotes.

I fiddled with the "Volume Control" settings in tvOS to no avail. I then power-cycled the Apple TV, fiddled with the settings again and the functionality re-appeared. Then a while later, the functionality disappeared again.

I'd rather not do this whole powercycle + fiddle with settings dance every other day.

Does anybody have an idea what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I bought some new batteries for the regular TV remote, the old ones were empty. Then that remote also stopped working for some reason.

I then reset the monitor to factory settings which fixed both the regular remote problems **and** the Apple TV remote also started working completely again.

Weirdness..

Comment: And this fixed stopped working again.

Comment: *This fix stopped working again.